# Remove number from array and shift the remaining ones

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, ecmascript-6

In JavaScript, having a number array like this:

```
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

How would you remove an element, for instance 3, and shift the remaining ones, so the resulting array is `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and not `[1, 2, 4, 5]`.

Currently I am using this snippet:

```
a.concat(a.splice(a.indexOf(3)).slice(1).map(b => b - 1));
```

but what would be an easier / more performant way?

**EDIT:**

Since I've been asked to provide more context, I have a Tabs like component and I need to keep track of the opened tabs by index. The user can also add and remove tabs, so if I have tabs 6 and 10 opened and the user removes tab 3, then the opened tabs become 5 and 9.

Comment: What is wrong with your current implementation? It looks like it works fine. Im guessing by shift, you mean decrement by one?

Comment: If you're actually using numbers, this seems pointless. Could you give some more context of the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @NickParsons popping an element would return the element. I want to remove an element and decrement the next ones by 1.

Comment: Is the array always consecutive numbers? The output will be same if you remove `3`  or `1`. So, is it irrelevant?

Comment: @Kobe I find it a little verbose and uses too many auxiliary arrays

Comment: @jonrsharpe why it seems pointless??

Comment: I said it *seems* pointless - why *don't* you just pop the last value, given the result is the same? What's the actual context?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't need to pop the last value, I need to pop a given index an decrement the remaining ones by 1.

Comment: Yes, but *why*? That's what I mean by context.

Comment: @jonrsharpe does it really matter?

Comment: @jonrsharpe because.... lol The data is probably not sequential numbers.... lol

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes it is

Comment: @epascarello well, perhaps, but I want *the OP* to confirm that. The rest of us can only speculate.

Comment: Yes, it matters, because otherwise we waste time solving an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @jonrsharpe not an XY problem. As I stated, I find this solution a little verbose and I uses too many auxiliary arrays, so I am concerned about performance and looking for alternatives :)

Comment: How does an array of consecutive numbers map to whether the tabs are open or not?

Comment: @jonrsharpe the tabs component has an array of children tabs, so I have to check whether a tab is opened or not to render accordingly.

Comment: But how does *this array*, of what just seems to be index + 1, relate to any of that?

Comment: @jonrsharpe supose I have 20 tabs / panels / wathever rendered but only 9 and 15 are opened. Now the user removes tab 3. I have to rerender the whole component keeping the previous state, so now tabs 9 and 15 become 8 and 14, because the user has removed tab 3.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. What I *don't* see is how this array of consecutive numbers starting from 1 that's the same length as that array of tabs (as I understand it, those things are always the case) is helping you with that at all. For example, why not just render with `.map((tab, tabIndex) =>` then use `tabIndex + 1` for whatever you're currently using this array's values for? And if those things *are* always the case, again, why *not* get the same result by just popping the last, now-unneeded value?

Answer (score 2):

You could start with the index of the number and adjust all other following value. At the end pop the last item.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 94, 95], // 9x, to show the use of the values
    remove = 3,
    index = array.indexOf(remove);
    
while (index + 1 < array.length) array[index] = array[++index] - 1;

array.pop();

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Originally a variation of Nina's, but after an edit, quite a lot different.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 94, 95],
  remove = 3,
  index = array.indexOf(remove);
  var res;
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    res = array[i];
    if (array[i] > 9) res = parseInt(array[i].toString().split('').pop());
    if (res === index) array.splice(res, 1);
  }
console.log(array);
```

Comment: you need to decrement the `9x` values.

Comment: Thanks @Nina Scholz. Got mine working properly in the end!

Comment: the `9x` values are not to look, it was only to show that these values are used for calculating ...

Answer (score 0):

You could use reduce, if the index is less that the given index, then push the value, if it is equal, do nothing, and if it is greater, minus 1 and then push it:

```js
let a = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
const index = 2

console.log(a.reduce((a, e, i) => (i < index ? a.push(e) : i > index && a.push(--e), a), []))
```

This is the same code, just written more readable:

```js
let a = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
const index = 2

console.log(a.reduce((a, e, i) => {
  if(i < index) {
    a.push(e)
  } else if(i > index) {
    a.push(--e)
  }
  return a
}, []))
```

Performance-wise, this code is O(n), as there is only one loop, but so is your code. I wouldn't worry about performance, I would be worried if you were trying to handle something that relies on performance from the front end.